# Epstein zeta function for real quadratic number fields

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, zeta-functions

Let $K$ be a real quadratic number field and $\mathcal O_K$ its ring of integers. Then
$$q:K\to \mathbb Q,\quad q(x):=\operatorname{tr}(x^2)/2$$
turns $\mathcal O_K$ into a positive definite lattice ($q$ is the quadratic form associated to the trace form $(x,y)\mapsto \operatorname{tr}(xy)$). So we can talk about the Epstein zeta function
$$\zeta({q,s}) := \sum_{0 \ne x \in \mathcal O_K} q(x)^{-s} = 2^s\sum_{0 \ne x \in \mathcal O_K} \operatorname{tr}(x^2)^{-s}.$$

I want to learn more about this zeta function. Is there a connetion to the Dedekind zeta function? Where can I read more about it?

Comment: The quadratic form associated to $tr(xy)$ is simply $tr(x^2)$, not $tr(x^2)/2$.

Comment: @GreginGre Nope, when $q$ and $b$ are associated you want to have $q(x+y)=q(x)+q(y)+b(x,y)$.